# ZedGraph radar chart

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph, radar-chart

Does the ZedGraph API allow us to create a [radar chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)? An example of a radar chart can be seen at http://www.internet4classrooms.com/excel_files/radar_chart3.gif and is also listed below.

Language used: C#, getting data from a database dynamically and shown on the radar chart.

---

[image: Sample radar chart, from www.internet4classrooms.com/excel_files/radar_chart3.gif]

Comment: There's multiple, please give us 1) language 2) used context 3) does it need to be dynamic or is static good enough.

Comment: oops. I'm sorry for the lack of information. Language used: C#, getting data from database dynamically and shown on the radar chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in ZedGraph using polar plot or any similar type of chart, here is some example:

[link broken] http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Polar_Plot_Demo

This should show you how you can do a chart like this. It shouldn't be any problem.

maybe also take a look on this example:

[link broken]
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Contour_Chart_Demo

Comment: The two links to zedgraph.org are (effectively) broken now.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it in ZedGraph, but I did come across this example in VB.NET (it could probably easily be translated to C#) for a different charting application: *[OpenFlashChart - A radar chart example with VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/cp_ofc_vb.aspx)*.